# How to find all zero byte files in directory

Tags: linux, shell-script

How to find all zero bytes files in directory and even in subdirectories?

I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lns=`vdir -R *.* $dir| awk '{print $8"\t"$5}'`
temp=""
for file in $lns ; do
    if test $file = "0" ;then
        printf $temp"\t"$file"\n"
    fi
    temp=$file
done
```

...but I got only files in that directory, not all files,
and if any file name had a space I got only the first word followed by a tab.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Question also posted on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15703664/7552) - please don't post the same question in multiple places.

Comment: ok i never repeate it again

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`find` is an easy way to do this-:

```
find . -size 0
```

or if you require a long listing append the `-ls` option

```
find . -size 0 -ls
```

Comment: can i filter files in a directory other than *.xml files

Comment: Yes you can - `find . ! -name \*.xml -size 0`

Comment: @Civa You can even do `find . -empty`

Comment: Yes indeed `-empty` will return zero sized files and empty directories.

Comment: `-empty` is non-standard and not supported on a minimal, POSIX compliant `find` implementation

Answer (score 0):

`find` will include all files and directories under the paths given as parameters, filtering them based on rules given as additional parameteres. You can use

```
find "$dir" -type f -name 'glob*' -size 0 -print
```

Some `find` implementations does not require a directory as the first parameter (some do, like the Solaris one) and will default to the current working directory (`.`). On most implementations, the `-print` parameter can be omitted, if it is not specified, `find` defaults to printing matching files.

- `"$dir"` gets substituted by the shell with the value of the `dir` variable (as from question)
- `-type f` limits it to files (no directories or symlinks)
- `-name 'glob*'` limits it to file that have name matching `glob*` (filenames starting with `glob`). To include all files, omit this
- `-size 0` only includes files with a size of 0 (the same in all units, for non-zero values, `c` needs to be included to check the file size in bytes)
- `-print` is the action to perform with matching files. `-print` will print the filenames. It can be omitted on standard compliant `find` implementations. If it is not present `-print` is implied.

Answer (score -3):

you can try this:

```
ls -l | awk -F " " '{if ($5 == 0) print $9}'
```

Zero byte file of working dir.

Comment: The most general reason why this is wrong: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).